# My newest computer has continually given me an extremely specific network issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, download, wifi-configuration

Let me start this out by saying this is not a router issue, nor an adapter issue. I have been on this same router, with the same adapter, on the same network with an older computer, and I never ran into this issue.

Basically, any time I'm downloading something, it'll start fairly normally. Until, eventually at some random time, the download speed will start going down. But that's not it, it jumps down, it'll be at about 3 Mbs, jumps down to 1, and keeps jumping down in increments every second until it eventually hits 0 bytes/second, and it never rises back up. If it's not a download from Steam or something, anything that has a force resume function, I have to force a network error by turning off wifi, then turning it back on, or I have to wait a very, very long time for it eventually to run into a network error on its own, but that takes a good few minutes. Then I can click resume, and it continues downloading, until it hits that error again. It doesn't affect anything but downloads, and this kind of error doesn't happen on my phone, nor did it happen on the same network, with the exact same adapters, on my old computer. I also, like I said, have a bunch of these LAN adapters, and I used to try to switch them out in an attempt to fix it. Now, I've just given up on that avenue of fixing it, as it clearly is not an issue with a specific adapter. I'm at my wit's end, but the worst bit of it all is that I have spent almost all day babysitting a launcher that doesn't have the aforementioned Steam auto-resume feature, or whatever it may be called. It would get a download error every few minutes, and I would just have to hit resume. But when I finally got to the end of it, I was finally done, the launcher slapped me and my hard work with a failure message, and the download bar, which I had spent my blood, sweat, and tears to make sure it would reach the end eventually, got cruelly set back to 0%. I've had enough of letting this tyrannical network issue bully me into babysitting all of my downloads. Please, help me out.

Comment: What OS are you using? Reading this, I see that the only cause could be the communication between the adapter and the computer, so maybe you should try searching for the official drivers for the adapter.

Comment: @InnPalz I'm using Windows 10, but like I said, the issue persists across all the different adapters I have. And with this same adapter, I had no issues on my last computer. The problem is in the computer itself, but I have no clue where to start with it. That's the issue here.

Comment: I would find a spare hdd you can wipe.  Disconnect all existing drives, and only have the spare hdd.  Install Windows on that, and see if you still have the issue.  If yes, its a hardware issue, if no it's software.  You could also try "safe mode with networking support"

Comment: @cybernard I'm in safe mode with networking, and the launcher I was talking about is actually working fine now. Thanks for the help, though I wish a fix for my troubles in normal mode could be found, I'm fine with stopping the search for a fix here. Still, hit me up if you got any ideas for fixing it in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and "in-place" windows upgrade.

Google "windows media creation tool".

*I would tell you to launch it in safe mode, but I don't know if that works or not for this program.*

Launch it and tell it to install windows.

Then set it to keep all your setting and programs.

Unfortunately this requires a large download.

For your own sanity I recommend getting a USB thumb drive and doing it on another computer.  Tell Media creation tool to use the thumb drive, you will need at least 5gb of space and its going to format the thumb drive.

Then pop the thumb drive into the broken computer and install windows from it.